# How to get foreign key used tablenames

Tags: mysql, jpa, entity, primary-key

I used JPA and mysql.
Each table have entity class.I have four tables.

**Table1 : student_table**

```
studentId(PK), studentName 
1              jack
2              robert
3              tom
4              smith
```

**Table2: roll_table**

```
rollId(PK), studentId(FK) 
10001          1
10002          2
10003          3
10004          4
```

**Table3: address_table**

```
addressId(PK)  City          studentId(FK) 
1               Washngton       1
2               NewYork1        2
3               Newyork2        3
4               Wasington2      4
```

**Table4: contact_table**

```
------------------------------------------------
contactId(pk) phoneNumber email studentId(FK) 
------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------
```

Base table is 'student_table'. 'studentId' is primary key for this table.

The remaining 3 table have used this studentId as foreign key.
Totally 3 table contains data. one table doesn't have any data.

**I need to write query for "studentId = 2 used table names and tables count if data exist other tables.
otherwise is there Any other logic to get this information.**

Like now the studentId = 2 used two tables. So the result is *(roll_table,address_table)*
Suppose contact table have data with studentId=2, 
then the result is *(roll_table,address_table,contact_table)*

Help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html): you want to use outer joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try left join which help you to display all the records from lefttable(studentName), even there are no matches on right table(roll_table,address_table,contact_table)

```
    SELECT student_table.studentId,student_table.studentName
 FROM student_table
 LEFT JOIN roll_table ON student_table.studentId = roll_table.studentId
 LEFT JOIN address_table ON student_table.studentId = address_table.studentId
 LEFT JOIN contact_table ON student_table.studentId = contact_table.studentId
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. suppose i used the foreign key in 1000 tables...i need to add more number of lines query.is right?

Comment: I expect the studentId used table names only(data exist), when execute query.. Here 3 tables refer studentId. but two tables data have point to student_table. In future i don't know, how many tables are refer that studentId

Comment: in this case use Inner Join instead of Left join which display only if there are matched studentID

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
         WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'Your base table name'
         AND TABLE_SCHEMA='DataBaseName' 
         AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'coloumnName'
```

Example

```
 SELECT * FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
         WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'student_table'
         AND TABLE_SCHEMA='student_dataBase' 
         AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'studentId'
```

Comment: Thanks eswar. But when i execute this query, it return all table names. (It contains empty table name also). I need table names if data exist.